# Determining network status in python on Linux based systems

Tags: python, networking

I just want to find out network status (i.e., UP/DOWN) for an interface in python.
I used following method using a python library called "netifaces"

```
addresses_for_iface=netifaces.ifaddresses(iface_name)
    if addresses_for_iface.has_key(netifaces.AF_INET):
        net_status = "UP"
```

Is this the best and efficient method to find out the status?

Anyone have suggestions for a better method?

Comment: Linux based system

Comment: What do you mean by "up or down"?  Do you mean...the interface has a link?  The interface has an IP address?  The interface has connectivity to remote hosts?  Or do you mean that the system somehow believes the interface to be up, separate from any of the above conditions?

Comment: UP/DOWN means if the interface has internet connection or not.